# Using .data to add data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have two spans on my site:

`<span class="view-toggle"></span>`

And I'd like to firstly set `data-status="inactive"` (to clear it of any settings), and then add `data-status="active"` to one element.

I have the following:

```
$('.view-toggle').find().data("status","inactive");
$(button).data( "status", "active");
```

I can confirm that `$(button)` correctly identifies the one span that I want to add `active` to.

I'm not getting any console errors, but I'm also not getting the addition of any data attributes.

Am I using `data()` incorrectly?

Comment: What's with the `.find()` without a selector? From the documentation: _Unlike most of the tree traversal methods, **the selector expression is required** in a call to .find()._

Answer (score 2):

The **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** method doesn't make any sense in your code just remove that.

```
$('.view-toggle').data("status","inactive");
$(button).data("status", "active");
```

---

Use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method if you want to reflect the attribute value in HTML code.

```
$('.view-toggle').attr("data-status","inactive");
$(button).attr("data-status", "active");
```

---

Refer : [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: OK, so how does one correctly use `.data()` - is this not the use for it?

Comment: @user1486133 :  see the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of .find() , without any selector.

To set any attribute use .attr("attr-name","attr-value");
And to get the attr value use .data("data-status");